# Website showing error log after running Magento Setup:static-content:deploy -f ..?

Tags: magento2, static-content-deploy

I am creating magento website and run stativcontent deploy -f after that i get Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/home/soft/public_html/megahaat.tk/var/cache/" is not writable in ..
how to fix it

Comment: if you are using linux environment Run the command from magento root directory "chmod -R 0777 var/ pub/ generated/" to give permission

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux in your magento root directory in command line 
run `sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache/`

Comment: its working but website load not properly

Comment: can you share url or screen shot if styles and java script is not loading please make sure you run
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Give Permission Cache folder

**Run the command from magento root directory**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/cache
```

Also give the permission of pub/static folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /pub
```

Comment: This error coming many time after run the commond

Answer (score 0):

1) Please set var folder 777 permission to use command in CMD `sudo chmod -R 777 /var` or `sudo chmod -R 777 /pub`

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

2) When you using FTP please set permission

[image]

Comment: Get repeating same error after upgrade setup

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux in your magento root directory in command line run sudo chmod -R 777 var/cache/

after

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```