# Invalid template file magento2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, windows, wamp

I have recently installed magento latest version i.e. Magento 2.3.0 in local wamp machine with `php 7.2.4`

Installed it using command line interface.

But when i tired to run it show me error like

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'D:/wamp64/www/mage23/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'
```

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: no still not working all extenssion are there.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Yes, This is the problem with windows. Windows uses "\" as separator, the array "directories" contains entries with "/" as separator, so the check will always fail.
So you need to fix this by replacing the separator in core file:

```
Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator
```

function **isPathInDirectories** replace below code in **isPathInDirectories** function

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Comment: This is a very common issue, Many people are not aware of the fact that Magento does not officially support Windows servers! some hacks and un-official modifications such as this one needs to be done in order to make it work on a Windows machine, If you visit the below link "Magento 2.3.x technology stack requirements" you can see that the only supported OS is "Linux x86-64". https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: for windows system what should be the actual code ? i am trying '\' line in first but this single back-slash is not allowed ...

Comment: Okay, so I get that they don’t officially support Windows, but couldn’t they just use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` like the rest of the world and not have this specific problem which seems like the only thing from working it in Windows?

Answer (score 22):

For me, solution worked is by going to the file \vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php and replacing the below function definition as below:

> ```
>  protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories) {
>      if (!is_array($directories)) {
>          $directories = (array)$directories;
>      }
>      $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
>      $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
>      foreach ($directories as $directory) {
>          if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
>              return true;
>          }
>      }
>      return false; }
> ```

PS: This is windows specific issue.

Comment: An even better solution is this one as it doesn't break linux compat: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/5774

Answer (score 6):

Magento 2.3 does not support windows.
You can find my solution here:
[enter link description here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19480)

Comment: it makes no sense for it to not support windows but has such a simple "fix".

Comment: You should post the solution here, instead of just providing a link.

Answer (score 4):

In Magento 2.2.9 replace /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php isPathInDirectories function code with this code

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if (0 === strpos(str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)), $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's the core issue of not just Magento 2.3.0, but I faced that problem in Magento 2.2.7 as well. In order to make the code work on windows instead of using realpath just use the $path argument passed to the method

Go to path /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php and instead of the line

```
if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
```

use

```
if (0 === strpos($path, $directory)) {
```

Or follow this discussion https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19480

Comment: This fixes the same problem that I've got on a Linux machine. However, I really don't understand why, since `$path` and `$realpath` is always exactly the same! I've added some var_dumps to find that out. Do you have any idea why this works?

Comment: Okay, that has probably something to do with [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261014/12971).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the issue is Windows compatability. But I would recommend to change it a bit differently to work even when migrating systems, e.g. for local development on Windows and later deployment on a Linux server. So that only in case you are operating on Windows you will adjust the path.

In

> \vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

in

> function isPathInDirectories()

replace

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

with:

a) PHP >= 7.2:

```
if (PHP_OS_FAMILY === 'Windows')
  $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
else
  $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

b) PHP < 7.2:

```
if (strtolower(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'win')
  $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
else
  $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please See that,It should be double slash i.e "\\"

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably happens when developing under Windows System.

Go to line 140 in file Path /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php 
    Replace this code of line

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

With

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Beware of this line of code

```
$realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

This won't probably work because of the php backslash scape. you have to do double backslash to tell PHP explicitly that it is not dealing with new line here but a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I set only one colon in xml file in path for template like this Vendor_Modulename:product/view/template.phtml but the the write way is to Vendor_Modulename::product/view/template.phtml. It may be invisible error

Answer (score 0):

in magento 2.4 Validator.php path is:

....\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

Answer (score 0):

for the latest magento 2.4.5

if you want to run with windows you have to change in below file
C:\xampp8\htdocs\magento244\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

```
 $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

replace with

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

after above change function look like below

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
{
    if (!is_array($directories)) {
        $directories = (array)$directories;
    }
    //$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
    $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
    foreach ($directories as $directory) {
        if ($directory !== null && 0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```