# Magento 2.2.7 Enterprise Edition Error in frontend | Invalid template file: '.../page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'

Tags: magento2, error, admin-panel, frontend-error, xampp

i have installed Magento 2 of version `2.2.7 EE` and `2.2.6 CE`. After installing i am getting this error in frontend and admin panel as well.

Errors i am getting:

**1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/mage227ee/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'**

[image]

or

**Blank page**

My current System:-

- Windows 8
- XAMPP /php 7.1.26 /MariaDb 10.1 /Apache 2.4
- 8GB RAM

I have tried multiple attempts of command with:

- `php bin\magento` or `php bin/magento`
- setup:upgrade
- setup:static-content:deploy -f
- indexer:reindex
- setup:di:compile
- cache:flush

Then i tried with the following approaches:

- composer update
- increased memory limit in index.php by adding `ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');`
- increased memory limit in `user.ini`, `.htaccess` and other locations as well.
- No errors found in `error.log` and `access.log` in `apache2/log` folder.

Can anyone help me a on how to approach to solve it.
thank you.

Comment: This below link helped me to fix it [please click here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/invalid-template-file-magento2-3-0)

Answer (score 0):

the error still exists. I tried the last approach, but now again the issue came, 
and i am getting blank page.