# Invalid template file issue in Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am seeing invalid template file error

> Invalid template file: 'Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'header.right.custom.area'

I have tried doing **view in small letters and View in camel case letters** but nothing works , I have tried **template** and **templates** both but no success .

> **.phtml file** is in **Sam/Options/view/frontend/templates/after_nav_banner.phtml**

I have cleared cache delete cache folders tried everything.
What can be the issue?

Block code is this:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.right.custom.area" template="Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">
```

template file C:\xampp\htdocs\learnm2\app\code\Sam\Options\view\frontend\templates\after_nav_banner.phtml
xml file 
C:\xampp\htdocs\learnm2\app\code\Sam\Options\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

Comment: Check the module `Sam_Options` enable or Not?

Comment: @AmitBera it is showing error on homepage i think it means module is enabled ? 
but as per you saying i have checked it yes it is enabled

Comment: have you checked this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/invalid-template-file-magento2-3-0?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @magefms i have tried it ... in the core file validator.php if we change
$realPath = str_replace("\\", "/", $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
this line to 
$realPath = str_replace("\", "/", $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
its shows error and if i change this line to 
$realPath = str_replace("\\", "\", $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
it shows error ...

Comment: so your original is already like :  $realPath = str_replace("\\", "/", $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path)); ?

Comment: try to di:compile, then upgrade, then deploy static view

Comment: yes original is already like that

Comment: ok compiling and upgrading

Comment: no success @magefms

Comment: Where did insert this `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.right.custom.area" template="Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">` in which file ?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\learnm2\app\code\Sam\Options\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

Comment: Have you solved it ?

Comment: no still not solved , i have almost tried each and everything ... but no luck

Comment: one thing to tell you i have added this template and block xml code in magento_theme in my theme and it is working there but not in my custom module

Comment: Have you created a "Block" folder in your module?

Comment: I have tried creating block either but no luck .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<block class="Sam\Options\Block\YourBlockNameHere" name="header.right.custom.area" template="Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">
```

Comment: still the same issue ...

Comment: <block class="Sam\Options\Block\Check" name="header.right.custom.area" template="Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">

Comment: Do some  echo `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` in `after_nav_banner.phtml` then add this : `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Sam\Options\Block\Check")->setTemplate("Sam_Options::after_nav_banner.phtml")->toHtml();?>` in another phtml and tell me if you that echo

Comment: I have tried echo thing but didnt work ... i have added simple h1 tag with text but not working ... i have switched to ubuntu lets see maybe things will work smooth now but thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your template file inside this path:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\learnm2\app\code\Sam\Options\view\frontend\templates\banner\after_nav_banner.phtml

Call it in your block like this:

> `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.right.custom.area" template="Sam_Options::banner/after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">`

Comment: I have tried the exactly same way ... 100% same way to solve this issue but not fixed either

Comment: have you tried this one `<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header.right.custom.area" template="after_nav_banner.phtml" after="navigation.sections">`

Comment: yes tried that also but not working .