# Problems With Magento installation

Tags: magento2, error, installation, static-content-deploy

I tried to install Magento 2.3, but I have problems with main page. I follow up the wizard installation and obtain the successful installation page. Now, when I try to access to my page, I see this:

[image]

I inspect the page and I get many errors

[image]

And My admin page show this

[image]

I get this result if I inspect the admin page

[image]

So, I search many post about installation errors and I find a commands to deploy static files in magento, so, I execute this

[image]

(I executed the commands in another installation)

And Now, My page don't show anything

[image]
[image]

And the admin page doesn't exist

[image]

Well, I need a little need help to resolve my problem.

Thanks

Comment: Did you give proper permissions to the files and folder ?

Comment: Yes, It's a Local installation in windows and it have permission

Comment: Try changing the mode to developer, and uncomment #ini_set('display_errors', 1); in app/bootstrap.php (this will let you know in case of any error). Run di:compile as well

Comment: @NarendraVyas I don't understand what you want me to do

Answer (score 1):

I finded the solution to my problems in this post [Invalid template file magento2.3.0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/invalid-template-file-magento2-3-0)

For somebody, if you installation is in windows, apply those changes and Magento works fine