# Notice: Undefined property: Test\Module\Block\StockLeft::$_registry in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento2\app\code\Test\Module\Block\StockLeft.php on line 28

Tags: magento2, blocks, magento2.3.3

I am creating a module that show the product stock item dynamically, but it is giving error

> "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.3.3\app\code\Test\Module\Block\StockLeft.php on line 31"

`StockLeft.php`

```
<?php 

namespace Test\Module\Block;


use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class StockLeft extends Template
{
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getRemainingQty(){
        $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
        return $product->getQty();
    }

    protected function getCurrentProduct(){
        return $this->_registry->registry('product');
    }
}
?>
```

Template : `stockleft.phtml`

```
<?php
    echo $block->getRemainingQty()
?>
```

Layout : `catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout = "1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku"> 
            <block class="Test\Module\Block\StockLeft" name="productleft" template="Test_Module::stock_left.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your file with this content

```
<?php 

namespace Test\Module\Block;


use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class StockLeft extends Template
{
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        Registry $registry,
        array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }

    public function getRemainingQty(){
        $product = $this->getCurrentProduct();
        $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
        return $stockItem->getQty();
    }

    protected function getCurrentProduct(){
        return $this->registry->registry('product');
    }
}
?>
```

You've added some extra text here in line no : 31 in your code. You can compare below lines..

```
return $this->registry->registry(key: 'product');
```

replace this with

```
return $this->registry->registry('product');
```

Here **key:** is not require in your code.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: It is giving error "Deprecated Functionality: strpos(): Non-string needles will be interpreted as strings in the future. Use an explicit chr() call to preserve the current behavior in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2.3.3\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php on line 143"

Comment: Can you please let me know you PHP version ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/251924/invalid-template-file-magento2-3-0?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: Please follow this solution.

Comment: php version  7.3.10

Comment: Can you please try to downgrade your PHP version? Because some functions are not deprecated in php and still exist in Magento check here.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KVl2xpygeaQIEyeInsVDFH8TwETr8Iks/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: This bug already reported here to Magento https://github.com/SemanticMediaWiki/SemanticMediaWiki/issues/3579

Comment: Are you able to find any solution here?

Comment: yeah buddy, i downgraded my php to 7.2.24 and now it is giving error "Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Test\Module\Block\StockLeft::registry"

Comment: I've updated my answer **return $this->_registry->registry('product');** replace this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101071/discussion-between-vinaysirige-and-kishan-savaliya).